# Why is this driver expression not working?

Tags: python, drivers, lighting

as you can see here the strength of the light's property shoulds always be => 0 but the expression isn't working.
[image]

Comment: This is probably related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/78100/34236).

Comment: And as far as I know, the graph in the graph editor doesn't reflect the real value of a channel if a driver is involved. So the graph not flattening out isn't an indicator of the driver not working.